# json List MVC ajax controller

Tags: c#, json, ajax, list, select

i would pass a list of table's rows, and read the list from ajax. it is possible?

This is my error:
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'Id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult Lta(Int32)' in 'Mvc.Controllers.HomeController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Nome parametro: parameters

```
                                       $.ajax({
                                            type: "POST",
                                            url: "Lta",
                                            cache: false,
                                            data: { "Id": Id },
                                            success: function (response) {
                                                if (response.length > 0) {
                                                    var i=0;
                                                    var selectconfig = "{ ";
                                                    for (var lettera in response) {
                                                        i++;
                                                        selectconfig = selectconfig + response.Id + ':"' + response.Date + ' ' + response.name + '"';
                                                        if (i != response.length-1) {
                                                            selectconfig = selectconfig + ",";
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }                                                    
                                                $.each(selectconfig, function(key, value) {   
                                                        $('#LettereSelect')
                                                            .append($("<option></option>")
                                                                    .attr("value",value)
                                                                    .text(key)); 
                                                });
                                                }
                                            },                    
                                            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                                alert('Error - ' + errorThrown);
                                            }
```

---

```
        public JsonResult Lta ( int Id)
    {
        MvcEntities dbo = new MvcEntities();
        List<Mvc.table> _Lta = new List<Mvc.Table>();
        foreach (Mvc.table L in dbo.table)
        {
            if (L.Id == Id)
                _Lta.Add(L);
        }
        return base.Json(_Lta);
    }
```

Comment: Try adding `contentType: 'Application/json'` to the ajax request

Answer (score 0):

Here you're using non-nullable type `int Id` parameter, try to use in this way like `int? Id`.